# How do I loop through an array with multiple objects and list certain elements in solely Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, javascript-objects

This is the code I have written. I want the `listContacts` function to loop through the `contacts` array and log the first and last name of each contact to the console. When I run this though it only logs John Doe to the console. What am I missing here?

```
var contacts = [ 
  { 
    firstName : 'John',
    lastName : 'Doe',
    phone : '(512) 355-0453',
    email : 'johndoe@email.com'
  },
  { 
    firstName : 'Jane',
    lastName : 'Doe',
    phone : '(313) 641-2203',
    email : 'janedoe@email.com'
  },
  { 
    firstName : 'Suzie',
    lastName : 'Smith',
    phone : '(415) 604-4219',
    email : 'suziesmith@email.com'
  }
];  

   var listContacts = function () {
   for (var i = 0; i <= contacts.length; i++) {
   return contacts[i].firstName + ' ' + contacts[i].lastName;
   }
};

console.log(listContacts());
```

Comment: You should not `return` in the first iteration of your loop, as that way you never get any other iterations of that loop.

Comment: Just FYI, your condition should be `i < contacts.length`, not `<=`.

Comment: `for (let c of contacts) console.log( c.firstName + ' ' + c.lastName );`

Comment: `console.log(contacts.reduce( (p,e) => { return p+e.firstName+' '+e.lastName+"\n" }, "") );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `return` statement in your `for` loop is causing that loop to stop after the first iteration. Instead, you should log within the loop:

```
var listContacts = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        console.log(contacts[i].firstName + ' ' + contacts[i].lastName);
    }
}

listContacts();
```

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your speedy answer!

Answer (score 3):

Your `return` inside the loop construct will make your function exit immediately, so your loop will never iterate more than once. Therefore you only get to see the first entry. Instead collect the names in an array, and return that:

```
var listContacts = function () {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        result.push(contacts[i].firstName + ' ' + contacts[i].lastName);
    }
    return result;
}
// Turn the array to string by joining with a newline character:
console.log(listContacts().join('\n'));
```

A more compact way to do this, is with this ES6 code:

```
var listContacts = function () {
    return contacts.map(c => c.firstName + ' ' + c.lastName);
}
// Turn the array to string by joining with a newline character:
console.log(listContacts().join('\n'));
```

Comment: I'm a beginner at this if you couldn't notice ;) Thanks for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You are returning in your for loop and when the for loop executes, it sees a return statement and exits the function without executing the remaining elements of the array.

Here is something you could do:

```js
var contacts = [{
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  phone: '(512) 355-0453',
  email: 'johndoe@email.com'
}, {
  firstName: 'Jane',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  phone: '(313) 641-2203',
  email: 'janedoe@email.com'
}, {
  firstName: 'Suzie',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  phone: '(415) 604-4219',
  email: 'suziesmith@email.com'
}];

var listContacts = function() {
  return contacts.map(function(contact) {
    return contact.firstName + " " + contact.lastName
  })
};

console.log(listContacts());
```